# How to refresh a Firebase Session Cookie? (auth/session-cookie-expired)

Tags: firebase, session, cookies, firebase-authentication, session-cookies

My application uses a server-side Firebase session cookie. Everything from sign in to sign out is implemented with their [official way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) in mind. However, if I don't use the application for some time, the session cookie will expire eventually. I have two options:

1. sign out the user and redirect to the sign in page
2. silently re-authenticate the user by refreshing the session cookie on the server

No questions about option 1. How would I implement option 2, if possible, with Firebase though?

---

2. The only thing I have is the **expired** session cookie on the client and server. At the moment, my server has a middleware which would return an authentication error:

```
export default async (
  req,
  res,
  firebaseAdmin
) => {
  const { session } = req.cookies;

  if (!session) {
    return null;
  }

  const checkRevoked = true;

  return await firebaseAdmin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(session, checkRevoked)
    .then(decodedClaims => {
      return firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(decodedClaims.uid);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new AuthenticationError(error.message);
    });
};
```

Is there any way I can use the `auth/session-cookie-expired` error message to re-authenticate the user silently? Perhaps I shouldn't do this in the first place -- because of security issues -- and just go with option 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you can do is the following:

- Inactive sessions: If the user doesn't visit your site after some time and the session cookie expires, then you have to sign in the user again. This is the more secure option.
- Active sessions: You can refresh the session once in a while (active window). If the cookie is set to expire in 2 weeks. You can refresh once a day and mint a new cookie for 2 weeks (extending the session effectively). One way to do that is to validate the cookie JWT and then sign in the user (using same uid) with custom token (using REST API or client Node.js) and then mint a new session cookie JWT with that ID token and give it a new 2 week lifetime.